# Generating download file in memory for user to download with file name user set

Tags: javascript, html, file, save, savefiledialog

I'm generating file using javascript for user to download which looks like so:

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,Zm9vIGJhcg==">text file</a>
```

What I need is to get file name that user set when he saved the file so I can display it on my website.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't get the name that the user set. That is not secure.

Comment: **No**, what user inputs in the browser control is beyond the control and scope of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer is:**
You can't.

**Complicated answer is:**

You can create a script to pre-set name of the file by the user.
Just create some pop-up or prompt where you will ask for naming that file. 
After that you can edit download attribute by JavaScript and user will download file with that name. (if he doesn't change it in download dialog)
Something like this:

```js
var fileName = prompt("Please name your file", "OriginalFileName"),
fileLink = document.getElementById('file');
if(fileName!= null){
  fileLink.download = fileName;
  fileLink.innerHTML = fileName;
}
```

```html
<a download='OriginalFileName' id="file" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,Zm9vIGJhcg==">text file</a>
```

Live example on https://jsfiddle.net/6o2fxcvd/1/